# Time that a comet comes closer than earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I had to solve the following problem on an exam today:

> A comet is travelling on a parabolic path $r$ to the 'west', crosses the orbit of the earth (assume the orbit of the earth is circular with radius $R$), gets near to the sun. The closest approach of the comet to the sun is $\beta R$ for $0 < \beta < 1$. Calculate the time $\Delta t$ that $r < R$.

I have tried to solve this using the path equation for gravitation. This equation states that all paths are solutions of $d^2u/d\theta^2 + u = \gamma / L^2$ where $u = 1/r$ and $\gamma = M_{\odot}G$.

1. Solutions in general are of the form $u = \gamma / L^2 + A \cos(\theta) + B \sin (\theta)$.
2. I apply the condition that $u = 0$ for $\theta = \pm \pi/2$ to obtain that $B= 0$. Also $u = 1/ (\beta R)$ for $\theta =0$ implies that $A = \frac{1}{\beta R} - \gamma/L^2$.
3. Rewriting the path equation I obtain $u = \gamma / L ^2 (1 + e \cos (\theta))$ with $e$ some constant. I wrote it in this form because I know that this is a standard form for conical sections. However, I think I am making a mistake here.
4. Then I used the given information that the path is parabolic to set $e = 1$ en derive the quantity $L = \sqrt{\beta R \gamma}$.

Now I can use the fact that the angular momentum $L$ is known, the above equation of motion and the relation $L = mr^2\dot{\theta}$ to compute the time $\Delta t$ as $\frac{m}{L}\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1} \frac{1}{u^2 (\theta)}d\theta$

But there is problem. The boundary angles seem to be false. With the above path equation they become $\theta = \cos ^{-1} (\frac{1}{eR}-\frac{1}{e})$ and this seems unlikely. I was not able to evaluate the integral completely. Did I use the wrong approach to calculate the angular momentum?

Comment: the orbit of the earth is circular, your earth path is not a circular.

Comment: @Eli yes, it's an assumption to simplify the problem. But you can assume that the shape of the orbit of the earth does not have a big impact on the orbit of the comet which passes the earth from far.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think this is your problem?. so try to calculate the intersection points. so the result will be:

$$\phi_2-\phi_1=\text{const}\,\Delta T$$

Comment: I see that I have to compute those but how can I compute the intersection points if have not yet derived the width of the parabola?

Comment: You know the equation of the parabola $x_p,y_p$ and the equation of a circle $x_c,y_c$ so the intersection point is where $x_p=x_c$ and $y_p=y_c$

Comment: so you think my equation for the parabola is right? I thought I made a mistake in choosing my angles.